# Prove equation has only one root in a specific interval

Tags: functions, roots

Prove that the following equation has only one solution in the interval $[-\text{min}(a_i), +\infty]$:

$f(x) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i + x}\right)\times \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i b_i}{(a_i + x)^2}\right) 
- \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{a_i + x}\right) \times \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{(a_i + x)^2}\right)
=0$

$x\in \mathbb{R}$

$n>1$.

$a_i$ and $b_i,\,\, i=1,..., n$, are all positive real numbers.

$a_1> a_2> ... > a_n$

$a_i \neq a_j\quad\forall i, j = 1,..,n, i\neq j$.

The context of the problem is as follows:

1. $a_i$ are the squared singular values of a random matrix.
2. $b_i$ are the diagonal elements of a sample covariance matrix.
3. I tried solving the equation for different parameter values using Newton's method. It always converges when initialized at zero.
4. The plot of the function in the interval of interest always shows increasing function from the start of the interval, zero crossing, a maximum, then the function continuously decreases. The function approaches zero as $x$ increases following the peak value.

We note/can prove the following:

1. $f(x)$ has $n$ discontinuities at $-a_i$.
2. $f(x)$ is continuous in the interval of interest $[-\text{min}(a_i), +\infty]$ = $[-a_n, +\infty]$.
3. $\lim_{x \to +\infty} = 0$.
4. $\lim_{x \to -a_n} = -\infty$.
5. $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable in the interval of interest.
6. $f(x)$ can be put in the form:
   $f(x) = \sum_{\{i,j\}} \frac{a_i - a_j}{(a_i + x)(a_j + x)} \left(\frac{b_i}{a_i + x} - \frac{b_j}{a_j + x} \right)$ for all permutations of $\{i,j\}\subset\{1,...,n\}, i< j$.

I tried the following steps to prove that $f(x)$ has a single root in the interval $[-\text{min}(a_i), +\infty]$:

1. Assume $x_0\in [-\text{min}(a_i), +\infty]$ is a root.
2. Tried to show that $x_0$ is not a solution of $f^{'}(x)$, but the derivative expression is far more complex to figure that out.

Any suggestion for an alternative way to obtain the required proof?

Comment: If $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n$, then any real number $x\neq -a_1$ is a solution. So, is there any other hypothesis?

Comment: Thank you Pedro for your comment. I have added the condition: $a_i \neq a_j\quad\forall i, j = 1,..,n, i\neq j$.

Comment: If $n=1$, the equation reduces to $$\left( \frac{a_1 b_1}{(a_1 + x)^3}\right) 
-  \left( \frac{a_1b_1}{(a_1 + x)^3}\right)
=0$$ 
and again have infinite solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be clear that $n>1$. I have edited the post with further information.

Comment: $n>1$..post edited.